# Angular2 raw html custom attribute

Tags: angular

I want to insert Raw HTML I get from the server, that has custom attributes in some tags. Angular2 strips out the unknown attributes I need to preserve. I am also very open to alternative ways.

Currently angular2 is embedded into the non-angular page (can't change that), and jQuery selects tags based no their custom attributes so i need to preserve them

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="rawHtml">[custom] attribute not present</div>`,
})
export class App {
  rawHtml = '<span class="class" custom="custom">Text</span>';
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/sKVHUubK0ofUfmSdR5gO?p=preview

Just FYI, I have tried attr.custom, [attr.custom], [custom] without success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DomSanitizationService](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizationService-class.html) to do that

```
import { DomSanitizationService } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="rawHtml"></div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  private _rawHtml: string = '<span class="class" custom="custom">Text</span>';

  public get rawHtml() {
     return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._rawHtml);
  }

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) { }
}
```

**[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oFN8JQku6mMioeu7x8V?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I need

Comment: You're welcome! You can also use it as pipe http://plnkr.co/edit/PZLeyT8qsrbP5WKNA8v0?p=preview

Comment: In Angular 2.0.0-rc.6 it has been renamed to ```DomSanitizer```, see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html