# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'item-value' since it isn't a known property of 'td'

Tags: angular

I am trying to do following:

```
<tr id="row" *ngFor="let data of dataList">
   <td class="search-result" data-item-value="{{data.value}}">
      {{data.text}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here dataList is an array of object with prop value and text.

I am getting following error:

> zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'item-value' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. (""
>   *ngFor="let data of dataList">
>                                           ]data-item-value="{{data.value}}">{{data.text}}
>                                       
>        "): MultiListBoxComponent@24:66 ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:  SyntaxError {__zone_symbol__error: Error:
>   Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'item-value' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'td'. ("……}  Error: Template parse errors: Can't
>   bind to 'item-value' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. (""
>   *ngFor="let data of dataList">
>                                           ]data-item-value="{{data.value}}">{{data.text}}
>                                       
>        "): MultiListBoxComponent@24:66

Is value binding to custom attributes not allowed in angular 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
[attr.data-item-value]="data.value"
```

instead of

```
data-item-value="{{data.value}}"
```

Comment: Better solution, didn't know about it!

Answer (score 2):

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792409/5049472

You could use `DomSanitizationService` with a function generating `td`.